# Images not showing in jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, html

I am  creating a slide show image using HTML, php and jQuery, but the images do not appear. Ii do not know what the error is. I am new with the jQuery, and I know there must be some little mistake, but I do not know where to search and find it.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JQuery Slider</title>

<style type="text/css">
.slider{
  width:800px;
  height:350px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:30px auto;

}
.slider img{
 width:800px;
 height:350px;
 display:none;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Slider(){
 $(".slider#1").show("fade",500);

 }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="Slider();">
  <div class="slider">
    <img id="1" src="img/13052012438.jpg"border="0"alt="image1" />
    <img id="2" src="img/25052012442.jpg"border="0"alt="image2" />

    <img id="3" src="img/13052012439.jpg"border="0"alt="image3" />
    <img id="4" src="img/25052012441.jpg"border="0"alt="image4" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a space character  between the selectors, you are selecting an element with class of `slider` and ID of `1`.

```
$(".slider #1").show("fade",500);
       ---^
```

As IDs are unique, you can select the element using ID selector:

```
$('#1')...
```

Also note that numeric IDs are valid only in HTML5 documents. I recommend you to use a slideshow plugin like nivoSlider or Flexslider.

Comment: what you mean by adding space between selectors ??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the slider already created by the jQuery team?

http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: first i want the image to slide by itself second i do not know how to make the images related to the slider that you talk me about it.

Comment: if you read into the documentation, you'll see that you can make the image slide by itself, however it doesn't sound like you're open to this solution, so I won't waste anymore of my time.